# Issue Installing Knot Theory

Tags: import, installation, knots

I have been trying to install the Knot Theory package from the [knot atlas](http://katlas.org/wiki/Setup#Setting_the_Path), but have been unsuccessful. Firstly I tried the command

```
<< KnotTheory`
```

but received a failure message. I then proceeded to modify the directory using the the `AppendTo[$Path, "DIRECTORY"]` command, and still receive the same failure message.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Check if `$Path` contains your directory. Or specify the full pathname. B.t.w. you can also use `Needs`

Comment: The same with me "Get::noopen: Cannot open KnotTheory`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i downloaded and unzipped the package in

```
C:\Parent
```

Appended the path as it is explained:

```
AppendTo[$Path, "C:\\Parent"]
```

There were some errors during the import

```
<<KnotTheory`
ParentDirectory::nums: Argument File should be a positive machine-size integer, a nonempty string, or a File specification.
ParentDirectory::nums: Argument File should be a positive machine-size integer, a nonempty string, or a File specification.
ToFileName::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in ToFileName[{File,WikiLink,mathematica}].
ToFileName::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in ToFileName[{File,QuantumGroups}].
Loading KnotTheory` version of September 6, 2014, 13:37:37.2841.
Read more at http://katlas.org/wiki/KnotTheory.
```

but some of the functions work:

```
In[8]:= KnotTheoryVersion[]
Out[8]= {2014,9,6,13,37,37.2841}
```

Mathematica version: 12

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workaround for this problem. (The package is assumed to be unzipped in "C:/Parent" directory.)

(1) Find the "init.m" file in the directory "C:/Parent/KnotTheory".

(2) Open the file with a text editor, and replace the lines 51-53

```
    KnotTheoryDirectory[] = (File /.Flatten[FileInformation[ToFileName[#,"KnotTheory"]] & /@ ($Path /. "." ->Directory[])])
```

by

```
KnotTheoryDirectory[] = "C:/Parent"
```

(3) Save the "init.m" file.

(4) Add the installation directory to the search path:

```
AppendTo[$Path,"C:/Parent"]
```

(5) You can use the package by

```
Needs["KnotTheory`"]
```