# Unable to use KnotTheory

Tags: import, packages, knots

I've installed the KnotTheory package, following the instructions [here](http://katlas.org/wiki/Setup). But when I try to use it I get this error:

`$CharacterEncoding: The byte sequence {139} could not be interpreted as a character in the UTF-8 character encoding.`

Both `` << KnotTheory` ``  and `` Needs["KnotTheory`"] `` raise this error (I found that byte sequence {139} is for "<"). "Needs" also raises

`` Needs: "Context KnotTheory` was not created when Needs was evaluated". ``

Parent directory of KnotTheory is in the `$Path`, but it doesn't help.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Assuming you are on a PC. If you put the folder "KnotTheory" in: "C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications" and then load it using: "<< KnotTheory`" you willl get some warning messages about ParentDirectory and FileName. However, the package seems to work.

Comment: Have you seen my answer to <https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237034/>?

Answer (score 4):

I recall that Claus Ernst once asked me about that. It's time that we make the fix public and searchable:

Go into the file `init.m` on the `KnotTheory` package directory.
Then replace the lines

```
KnotTheoryDirectory[] = (
  File /. Flatten[FileInformation[ToFileName[#,"KnotTheory"]] & /@ ($Path /. "." -> Directory[])]
)
```

with

```
KnotTheoryDirectory[] = DirectoryName[$InputFileName];
```

Save the file, restart the kernel. Afterwards, the package should load just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it. It works for me, it loads and I can call its functions, but I keep getting warning `Get::path: ParentDirectory[File] in $Path is not a string.` even though it does give the same output as on the web site.

I think you need to edit `init.m` to fix these. It seems like old package.

There are the steps I did

download zip file. Extract the folder `KnotTheory`. Then did

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"Applications"}]
```

Which gives

```
"C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Applications"
```

Then copied the folder `KnotTheory` to the above folder. So now it looks like this

[image]

Now from Mathematica

```
Quit[]

<< KnotTheory`
```

Gives these warnings

[image]

But it works

```
 Alexander[Knot[6, 2]][t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I never used this package myself before. But the date on the webpage is 2013, which is old.

[image: Mathematica graphics]